# python flask dynamic URL creation with url_for()

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I have an ajax js function:

```
if (data.result == "Successfully joined"){
    window.location.href='{{ url_for( 'chat', name = "test" ) }}';
}
```

and function in python:

```
@app.route('/chat/<string:name>')
def chat(name):
    return render_template("chat.html", c=name, s="Janek")
```

but when my first (ajax js) is called, it results with 404 not found error. After removing additional variable name, everythink loads corectly. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 1**
the entire js is:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(function() {
        $('a#join_btn').bind('click', function() {
            $.post('/', {
                var1: $('input[name="cname"]').val(),
            }, function(data) {
                $('#result').text(data.result);
                if (data.result == "Successfully joined"){
                    window.location.href='{{ url_for( 'chat', name = "test" ) }}';
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**SOLVED:**
adding `methods=["POST"]` to `@app.route('/')` fixed the error for me.

Comment: Hi, would you mind giving a bit more of context? Where does the JS snippet come from?
At first glance the pieces you shared are sound from what I can tell.

Comment: can You look at my edit?

Comment: Thanks for the edition. You mentioned that your first ajax is failing with 404. Does that mean that the call `post("/"...` is failing? you didn't include that endpoint in your question.
Your use of `url_for` looks pretty legit to me and your `/chat/<string:name>` endpoint also look correct to me.

I'd double check the route function of the endpoint responding for the "/" is also including the method post (`@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])` that could be the source of your 404 if it's only allowing GET requests but your JS is trying to do a post instead)

Comment: Oh, yes. This including method post fixed the error. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

`@app.route('/chat/<string:name>')` should be `@app.route('/chat/<name>')`

Comment: can you further explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have a html page with button. I want to redirect to diffrent html page with some additonal values (to be able to use it e.g `{{ somedata }}` ) on button click

Comment: Is the html file containing the js served with render_template()?

Comment: but this script is in <head>  of my .html file

Comment: `@app.route('/join_chat')
def join_chat():
    return render_template("join_chat.html")`

Comment: `<div class="menu-item" id="2" onclick="window.location.href='{{ url_for( 'join_chat' ) }}';">Join Chat</div>` in **home.html** file

Comment: is the home.html also provided with render_template()?

Comment: from which to which page do you get the 404 error? and what url do you get redirected to?